# If one cuts the flower off a fruit tree, will a new flower/fruit grow in its place?

Tags: fruit-trees, flowers

If one cuts the flower off a fruit tree, will a new flower (and then the fruit) grow in its place?

Comment: What kind of fruit tree are we talking about?

Comment: Depends on the fruit tree, but generally, no, not in the same year.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with stormy, but I add some information.

The buds are already differentiated on spring, and there will be no additional flowering buds (really, the plant could produce new buds, that will flower in late summer/fall, or the usual buds for next year).  Note: this is true also for leave buds, and you will notice it after a strong freeze: the plant will take much time to recover, because it should create new buds and then let them grow the new leaves.

Additionally many fruit plants tend to have two phases: one year of main green growth, and one year of main fruiting (and flowers) growth. Note: pruning will reduce such "alternance" and favor fruiting.

Cutting the flowers (so the hormones produced by flowers) will signal the plant to go to the green phase, and get less energy to existing fruits.  This is done by humans to force growth of young plants, but also naturally, e.g. when flowering season was bad (raining, freeze).

So cutting flowers will signal the plant to prefer green growth.

Comment: Well great information...Giacomo!

Answer (score 5):

No, not in the sense you are thinking.  The energy that would have gone into the fruit you removed went elsewhere; other buds for fruit, places the plant needed repairs or more vegetative growth to support the reproductive growth.  You are able to stop the energy leaks to allow that energy to go elsewhere. No 'new' flower or fruit but other flower buds will prosper with the excess energy you released to certainly make those buds make more seed/fruit.  Green leaves plus sunlight plus certain chemicals plus water air will either make more leaves or more reproductive growth and for perennials, roots with food storage that the plant itself made.  More hardiness.

Plants,  especially annuals, have but one directive in life; make seed.  Once that directive is completed, the plant dies.  Perennials are a bit more complex having more avenues for reproduction.  When you see a shrub that had been struggling for years all of a sudden bloom like crazy, it is a good sign that shrub is on its way to shrub heaven.  Its last burst of energy went into reproductive growth.

Cutting flowers off annuals as soon as they appear is one of the secrets to massive flower displays.  Needs a bit of give and take with the energy but yes, the more you cut off the more energy is returned to the plant.  Not another flower or whatever but where that plant could use that energy.

Comment: A technique used in commercial apple orchards is to spray trees with a chemical which causes them to drop some of their blossoms. So instead of a tree producing, say 1000 apples, it only produces 500 but each apple is larger. Same amount of energy, but directed differently.